# Monitor Workstation Issue

Tags: display

I have a problem with my computer. Below is the description, My monitor works well with one workstation. But when I use the same monitor with a different workstation, the computer powers up, but nothing is visible. What could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SU. This needs more information. What kind of a monitor is it? What kind of plug are you using to connect the monitor to the computer? Have you made sure the other workstation works with a different monitor? What kind of a workstation is it? Does it have multiple graphics connectors? Do you know the make and model of the graphics card in the other workstation?

Answer (score 2):

If nothing is being displayed, it could be anything.

Easiest thing (if completely blank/nothing):

If you have two (or more) video inputs, make sure you are using the correct one - Graphic cards usually override built in.

Next up, it could be motherboard or PSU failure.

For anything else, you really need to be more specific in the problem, however, I suggest you search here as there is bound to be many other questions that can help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows press F8 on startup. Select Start in VGA mode
If that works, reset your display settings to a resolution supported by your Monitor.